# Process writing to pipe does not terminate until output is consumed

Tags: bash, pipe, mkfifo

I want to use a pipe with `mkfifo` to capture all output from several processes running concurrently, roughly like the following

```sh
PIPENAME="/tmp/foo"
echo "Make ${PIPENAME:?}" && mkfifo "${PIPENAME:?}"

echo "hello 1" >"${PIPENAME:?}" &
echo "hello 2" >"${PIPENAME:?}" &
wait < <(jobs -p)
cat "${PIPENAME:?}" | sort | uniq
echo "Removing FIFO ${PIPENAME:?}" && rm "${PIPENAME:?}"
```

However, the above hangs and does not work, that is, none of the `echo "hello..." >"${PIPENAME}"` processes terminate so the script never gets to the wait line.

I guess a process writing to the pipe cannot terminate until its output was consumed from the other end?  If yes, what's the canonical way to achieve my goal here?  Again, I want to be able to start a few (less than 20) possibly long-running commands in parallel and have their outputs combined without loosing any lines.

Answer (score 2):

Since a `FIFO` is not a regular file but just the reference to a (named) pipe a process can write to it only after it was opened on both ends, see [`fifo(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html).

So your `echo` commands won't even start to write their output to the pipe but instead will block until another process is attached to the pipe for reading the output.

> what's the canonical way to achieve my goal here?

Depends greatly *what* your goal here is:

If you just want to combine the output of multiple commands before piping it to another command, use the group command syntax from [pjh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71530277/process-writing-to-pipe-does-not-terminate-until-output-is-consumed/71531034#71531034).

If you have to use a `FIFO` attach the reading process before `wait`ing on the writing commands:

```sh
echo "hello 1" >"${PIPENAME:?}" &
echo "hello 2" >"${PIPENAME:?}" &
cat "${PIPENAME:?}" | sort | uniq &
wait < <(jobs -p)
```

If you just want to collect the output for later processing just use a regular file instead:

```sh
LOGFILE="/tmp/foo"

echo "hello 1" >> "$LOGFILE" &
echo "hello 2" >> "$LOGFILE" &
wait < <(jobs -p)

# anytime later
cat "$LOGFILE" | sort | uniq
```

But be aware that with all of this solutions very long lines or unfortunate scheduling of the processes can lead to the output of one process to be placed *in the middle* of a line of another.

To prevent this you may need to use a proper logging tool.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some other reason for using a fifo, I think that what you are trying to do can be done with:

```
{
    echo 'hello 1' &
    echo 'hello 2' &
    wait
} | sort -u
```

Comment: Yeah, that works too.  I wasn't aware of the `{}` grouping syntax.  Thanks!